# change text in file with chef if exists and add if doesn't

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I know w/ chef you can add a line to a file if a pattern doesn't exist

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Util/FileEdit:insert_line_if_no_match

and you can even update a line in a file if the pattern does exists

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Util/FileEdit:search_file_replace_line

Is there a handy way to add if doesn't exist - and replace if does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write your own little helper?

```
def update_or_insert(regex, newline)
  search_file_replace_line(regex, newline) || insert_line_if_no_match(regex, newline)
end
```

This will return with the changes if it does find anything to replace, or return with the changes if it discovers that it needs to add the line in.